# issues with manual install of python module - both command line and interpreter

Tags: python, windows, installation

Just getting back into python and I'm having issues with a basic python module install on an XP machine. I'm determined not to take an "easy install" approach.

- a) I had no python on the XP machine.
- b) I downloaded "Python 2.7.3
  Windows Installer" from http://www.python.org./download/. no
  issues with the install (installed in C:/Python27)
- c) I downloaded
  xlwt 0.7.4 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt and this is where I have
  an issue. The readme of xlwt states: "Any OS: Unzip the .zip file
  into a suitable directory, chdir to that directory, then do "python
  setup.py install"."

With the files in the right directory, following the instructions does not seem to work because my command prompt does not recognize "python" as a term. (is this normal, or should I manually change my environmental variables??)

Seeing as this didnt work I read some info on [this website](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html) and decided to instead enter python interpreter from the command prompt and enter "setup.py install". This also did not work, with the interpreter stating:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
  setup.py install
                 ^
```

I'm not sure why it is not recognizing setup.py, since I'm in the right directory:

```
path = os.getcwd()
print =os.listdir(path)
```

which prints:

```
['HISTORY.html', 'licences.py', 'PKG-INFO', 'README.html', 'setup.py', 'tests',
'xlwt']
```

Am I missing something here, or are the readme instructions assuming I also do other things?

Comment: what's wrong with `easy_install` or `pip`?

Comment: won't learn as much:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python setup.py install
```

is meant to be entered on a command prompt, not into the Python interpreter.

It looks like your PATH environment variable is not set up correctly. Change it to include the directory where python.exe resides, and you should be able to run the setup.py script.

Comment: This is what I initially thought the problem was - but I just did a fresh install of python from python.org -- does that installation really require manual environmental variables? Also just "setup.py install" is meant for the interpreter is that right?

Comment: "python setup.py install" will run the program "python" with the arguments "setup.py install". Python, when given these arguments, will load the script "setup.py" with the arguments "install". And yes, it seems like you need to manually adjust your environment variables. Python should already be working on your computer, it's just not command-line-friendly yet. If you typed the full path to python.exe that would have worked. But of course, you don't want to have to do that every time...

Comment: good to know the manual enviro settings are needed. I am still curious why "setup.py install" did not work when I tried to do the install from the python interpreter?

Comment: Well, frankly, why did you expect that it would work? In the Python interpreter you're expected to type Python expressions -- not the names of Python files. If you type something like "34+5*6" or "open('hello.txt','r').read()" it'll compute the value of that expression and print it out. If you just want to run a Python file non-interactively, use the shell, using "python" before your script name. (If you want to work with code that you have saved to a file interactively in the interpreter, read about "import" in the documentation.)

Comment: I think I misread a statement in one of the pages I was looking at - I thought that the command line route was one option to installing a module, with the other option being from within the python interpreter...

Answer (score 0):

Hit `Start -> Run...`, type `cmd` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Type `cd \path\to\module\dir`. Enter `c:python27\python setup.py install` in the directory where the setup.py file resides and you should be good to go.